# Shell script that monitors CPU usage and terminates services with high CPU utilisation

Tags: windows, command-line, script, cpu-usage

We have a Windows 2003 server where 3 services are running constantly. Sometimes these services consume over 90% CPU. Restarting these services returns normalcy. I need a script/program that will constantly monitor CPU usage and if usage is high then restart those services.

After a bit of research I found this script to monitor CPU usage from [Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/b9d86bdc-9ea8-4659-ae65-4c1b5b86d324/).

Script to monitor CPU usage:

```
(get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
-SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 10 |
    select -ExpandProperty countersamples | select -ExpandProperty
cookedvalue | Measure-Object -Average).average
```

This monitors the CPU usage for 10 seconds and then displays the averaged output.

Also from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405372/stopping-starting-a-remote-windows-service-and-waiting-for-it-to-open-close) and [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/25081/how-do-i-restart-a-windows-service-from-a-script) I found the scripts to restart Windows services. (*Which one is better?*)

Now all I need is for the CPU usage script to call the service restart scripts when the condition that usage is >90% is met. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which services cause the high CPU usage? Use xperf to see which functions cause the usage.

Comment: We run an EPABX application on the server..the services are related to the same...I know the services..I only need a way out to restart them automatically when them automatically when they start hogging resources.

Comment: Yeah ... would be great if yo could specify what kind of Operating system are do you need it for. The solution for Linux is really easy - `mpstat -A | grep all | head -1 ` will give you CPU usage and based on its value you could restart the services. In windows i would advise to use powershell `Get-WmiObject win32_processor | select LoadPercentage  |fl` which will give you CPU usage and to restart services use command `sc` with proper switches/parameters.

Comment: It's Server 2003. @mnmnc I think that WMI script you worte would show the CPU usage at any particular instant. Now there can be a number of reasons that the CPU usage can suddenly spike. I specifically need a script that will monitor the usage for a period of time (say 10 seconds) then if it's >90%, will restart some specific services. I might add that the services don't stop instantly...so we need to wait some time/check their status to start them again.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should contact the creator of the tools and ask them why the service hogs the CPU.

Comment: If such a thing happens then these services are poorly programmed, you should contact developers to fix them before more serious problems start to pop up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the record..here's the **answer**:

```
$cpuutil=(get-counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5 |
    select -ExpandProperty countersamples | select -ExpandProperty cookedvalue | Measure-Object -Average).average

If ($cpuutil -ge 90)
{Restart-Service MyService1, "My Service2", MyService3}
Else
{Exit}
```

Powershell truly makes life simpler!

Answer (score 0):

If a commercial solution is OK, check out our [Service Protector](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceProtector/). It will babysit any windows service and restart it if it hogs the CPU for too long.

Comment: As I mentioned already...these are **NOT** windows services

Comment: @gh0sT - I'm confused - you've said that the OS is Win2003 server and now that those are not Windows services. I guess you might mean that the services are not created by Microsoft as in 'not shipped with Operating System' but a third party services running on Windows2003 server. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes..exactly..these are third party services