# I need a batch file that will be able to restart an EXE when the EXE only uses 10% cpu usage

Tags: windows-7, batch

I have currently been using this.

```
@echo off

set serverName=Server Restarter
title %serverName%

:restart
TIMEOUT /T 900
taskkill /F /IM ServerLauncher.exe /T
goto restart
```

Edit:

Right now I have this code in place. It automatically restarts the server after 15 minutes. But if it crashes before that time limit. It will not restart the EXE. You have to wait 15 minutes for it to restart again.

The server only crashes when the cpu hits about 10% cpu usage. It goes into a deadlock. So I'm looking for something that whenever the CPU usage hits that low on the specific process, to auto kill it, and restart. Any ideas?

Comment: "But it will not restart the process if it hits below 10% cpu usage" - You mean to say if CPU usage < 10% then taskkill doesn't work?

Comment: you have a strange way of finding a problem and fixing it.  You assume that what you have seen is a symptom of the problem, probably true.  But you need to add more monitoring into the system to more throughly investigate the problem.  Rebooting at 10% is not really a solution ESPECIALLY in a professional environment.

Answer (score 0):

As *mdpc* commented above this is more of a hack/workaround than a proper solution, but you asked for it so here goes...

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('"wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process Where Name='Idle' get PercentProcessorTime /value 2>NUL | find /i "PercentProcessorTime""') do set usage=%%a
if %usage% LEQ 10 (
    echo Time to restart server!
) else (
    echo Not yet...
)
```

I've used the "Idle" process in the code, so you need to replace that with the name of your process (if unsure see output of `wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name`).

Comment: Karan, this script of yours..wouldn't it measure the CPU Utilisation at a particular instant? Wouldn't it be better if it could monitor the usage for..say 5secs..and then average the output? I am interested in this question because I had a [similar] (http://superuser.com/questions/576252/shell-script-that-monitors-cpu-usage-and-terminates-services-with-high-cpu-utili/592897#592897) problem and figured out a PS script, however a similar functionality in batch would be great!

Comment: @Gh0sT: Yes, and averaging over an interval would probably require repeated calls to `wmic` and storage in a variable whose value needs to be updated. I'm sure a loop can be cooked up (probably without accurate timing since it's batch), but I leave the exercise to someone who's interested in extending what is already a hack. If I had to do this I would prefer a proper scripting environment such as PowerShell/VBScript any day. Just getting the quoting for the command was a PITA since `wmic` has weird quirks that interfere with usage inside a `for /f` loop. Why do you want batch over PS anyway?

Comment: Well PS trumps batch anyday..but it's just that batch is included in all versions of Windows. That's why I prefer batch for simple tasks such as these. But as you quite rightly pointed out, implementing this in batch would be a real 'PITA'! :)